# Is it possible to dump memory from one Ubuntu VM to another?

Tags: ubuntu, azure, memory, rdma

I'm trying to use Azure VMs to host a game server for me and some friends since spot instances are cheap, but the downside is that they get deallocated/deleted pretty quickly in practice (somewhere like every 30 mins when I was testing). So I'm trying to devise a way to spin up a new spot instance as soon as the old one gets an eviction notice, and then dump the memory from the first VM to the new one so it can carry on as the new game server, all without causing any pauses for the players. Does Ubuntu have built in methods or existing packages for RDMA? Or does anyone know if Azure supports this (I saw mention of RDMA for their HPC sizes but that's way too expensive for this use case)?

Comment: The very short answer is you can't do that unless the gameserver itself supports it. Without such support, spot instances are inappropriate.

Comment: Could you point me to more resources that explain why? (I'm curious about the subject). Even if I were to dump the entirety of the memory, "cloning" the VM so to speak, that wouldn't work? Why not?